# boost bind.hpp 1.54 c++ specialized template doesn't compile on Solaris. Valid C++?

Tags: c++, boost, solaris, template-specialization

When compiling Phusion Passenger for Solaris 10 SPARC using the Sun Studio compiler, these errors are seen in the included boost 1.54 headers. How can they be rewritten to solve the compilation error?

```
"ext/boost/bind/bind.hpp", line 69: Error: boost::_bi::F is not a namespace or class name.
"ext/boost/bind/bind_template.hpp", line 15:     Where: While specializing
"boost::_bi::result_traits<boost::_bi::unspecified, extern "C" int(*)(DIR*)>".
"ext/boost/bind/bind_template.hpp", line 15:     Where: Specialized in
boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, extern "C" int(*)(DIR*), boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<DIR*>>>.
"ext/common/ApplicationPool2/Spawner.h", line 250:     Where: Specialized in non-template code.
"ext/boost/bind/bind.hpp", line 69: Error: result_type is not defined.
"ext/boost/bind/bind_template.hpp", line 15:     Where: While specializing "boost::_bi::result_traits<boost::_bi::unspecified, extern "C" int(*)(DIR*)>".
"ext/boost/bind/bind_template.hpp", line 15:     Where: Specialized in boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, extern "C" int(*)(DIR*), boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<DIR*>>>.
"ext/common/ApplicationPool2/Spawner.h", line 250:     Where: Specialized in non-template code.
```

The problematic code is here:

```
56  // result_traits
57
58  template<class R, class F> struct result_traits
59  {
60      typedef R type;
61  };
62
63  #if !defined(BOOST_NO_TEMPLATE_PARTIAL_SPECIALIZATION) && !defined(BOOST_NO_FUNCTION_TEMPLATE_ORDERING)
64
65  struct unspecified {};
66
67  template<class F> struct result_traits<unspecified, F>
68  {
69      typedef typename F::result_type type;
70  };
71
72  template<class F> struct result_traits< unspecified, reference_wrapper<F> >
73  {
74      typedef typename F::result_type type;
75  };
76
77  #endif
```

The boost trouble ticket:
https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/9250

The boost bind.hpp source code:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/boost/bind/bind.hpp

The Phusion passenger tracking of the problem:
https://code.google.com/p/phusion-passenger/issues/detail?id=982

Answer (score 1):

From https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/9250

```
"ext/common/ApplicationPool2/Spawner.h", line 250 should contain something like
boost::bind(closedir, ...). It needs to be changed to
boost::bind<int>(closedir, ...). The problem is that on this compiler extern "C"
functions are distinct from ordinary C++ functions.
```

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/bind/bind.html#Q_extern_C

After chasing a rats nest of C++ template search results yeterday, I'm a little disturbed it's this easy a fix :)